# Google app engine 100 URLMap entries limitation

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I have been using google app engine to build my website, and met a problem about the maximum number of URLMap (I had 101 URLs, but the limit is 100). Here is the error message:

```
Fatal error when loading application configuration:
Invalid object:
Found more than 100 URLMap entries in application configuration
  in "\AppPest\app.yaml", line 269, column 28
```

I tried to change the setting `MAX_URL_MAPS = 1000` in the file appinfo.py, but it did not work. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

## EDIT:

Another question is that some of my URLs are similar, like a_input.html, b_input.html, c_input.html. Is there a way to simplify it in order to reduce the number of URLs? Here is an example of my yaml file

```
#a
- url: /a_input.html
  script: a/a_input.py
 
#b
- url: /b_input.html
  script: b/b_input.py

#c
- url: /c_input.html
  script: c/c_input.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will depend on the language you are using. If you are using python 2.7, what you can do is to:

1) Use regular expression for defining the urls, see [this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Script_Handlers) for more details

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*?)_input.html
  script: /input/\1.app
```

2) Point a group of urls to the same app and let the app handle the different requests.

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*?)_input.html
  script: /input/input.app

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/a_input.html', AInputPage), ('/b_input.html', BInputPage)])
```

From the information you provided I cant tell if a_input.html, b_html are static or not. But if they are static yo could also do:

3) Refer them with the [static file handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers), which also accept regular expressions.

```
- url: /input
  static_dir: static/input
```

See [issue 1444](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1444) for some more details, specially for java related ones.

Comment: Thanks for helping with this. I like the way to group URLs, but is it possible for my case (please see my edits)?

Comment: Yes, you need to use method 1), please refer to the docs I pointed. Here is the code (sorry, no formatting in comments):- url: /(.*?)_input.html  script: \1/\1_input.py. Next time, please specify what runtime you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Java SDK.
I revolved removing index.html from welcome-file-list.
Now my entrypoint is index.jsp with a redirect to my index.html page.

In web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In appengine-web.xml:

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/fonts/**" />
    <include path="/app/fonts/**" />
    <include path="/**.html" />
    <include path="/**.js" />
    <include path="/**.css" />
    <include path="/**.ico" />
    <include path="/**.png" />
    <include path="/**.jpg" />
    <include path="/**.jpeg" />
    <include path="/**.gif" />
</static-files>
```