# overcome the 100URL limit in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a php app, for the app engine. My app.yaml file is the following:

```
application: myproject-testing-112
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /edit.php
  script: edit.php

....

- url: /profile.php
  script: profile.php
```

my problem is that I have about 300 urls (i have 300 php files). As I can see app.yaml allows you 100 URLS. How to deal with this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: thank you. I have seen this answer. Was for python. What I have to do in my case, because I use php. Any example to see how to move on?

Comment: got any idea if I can group my urls, in the above example? I want to let it in php because it is hard to change everything in python now...

Comment: You could use a Regex Pattern as shown in the [Google Docs (php)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers) and in this [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298401/google-app-engine-100-urlmap-entries-limitation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex patterns with PHP GAE just like in the Python GAE example referenced in the comment. So, give the following a try:

```
application: myproject-testing-112
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.php).*
  script: \1
```

To be clear, this one entry will map every URL that matches to a PHP file of the same name.

```
/edit.php --> edit.php
/profile.php --> profile.php
/profile.php/foobar --> profile.php (the ".*" at the end of the regex allows this behavior)
/someOtherPath will not match the above entry at all, since it doesn't have ".php"
```

Obviously, you can tweak the regular expression to get the exact behavior you're looking for.