# App.Yaml over 100 URLMap entries limitation

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having trouble updating my (python) app.yaml file to overcome the 100 urlmap limit.

Another StackOverflow [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298401/google-app-engine-100-urlmap-entries-limitation) proposed the following input...

```
- url: /(.*?)_input.html
  script: /input/\1.app
```

but for the life of me I can't get this to work.

I have numerous entries like

```
- url: /somethingmaint.html
  script: fsomethingmaint.app
```

('something' is the text which changes) which I should be able to convert to a single entry like that already proposed.  I have tried a number of combinations, the latest of which is...

```
- url: /(.*?)maint.html
  script: f/input/maint.app
```

Any pointers for me? Thanks, David

Update
- I have removed the 'code' from my app.yaml and returned updated index.py to suit.  It now means that the app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([...]) section is 100 lines long and growing, at least it now works.

Thanks all.

Comment: why would you have over 100 python app scripts? can't you combine them?

Comment: @marcadian - I have a large number of different .html files for maintenance, each has their own .py file which contains the app = webapp2.WSGIApplication( segment.  So a.html is controlled by fa.py ... z.html is controlled by z.py.  Not sure how I could combine them without making a mess.

Comment: @DavidFreeman is there anything similar in all of this html handler? or each of them is unique?

Comment: You don't really need to init the WSGIApp for each file, you can create a single file and aggregate all route mapping from each file and init the WSGIApplication.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @marcadian, I have removed the 'code' from my app.yaml and returned updated index.py to suit. It now means that the app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([...]) section is 100 lines long and growing, at least it now works.

Thanks all.